# Does Microsoft DependencyInjection support non-constructor injection?

Tags: dependency-injection, .net-4.6.1

I am trying to incorporate `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` into an **existing** ASP.NET 4.6.1 app.

I know that while .NET Core has it built-in, for 4.6.1 you need to create some initial classes as outlined in http://scottdorman.github.io/2016/03/17/integrating-asp.net-core-dependency-injection-in-mvc-4/. (The article seems to be out of date since the sample code does not show implementation of `BeginScope()` and `Dispose()` for `IDependencyResolver`. If anybody has more updated examples that would be appreciated.)

"Services" accessed by controllers where you are creating instances via **constructors** is fairly simple but my problem is when I need an instance of "something" that is from a property or method of an existing object.

For example, I have a inherited `DbContext` that needs an instance of System.Security.Principal.IIdentity that comes from the logged in user.

Another example is an instance of `ApplicationUser`. `ApplicationUser` inherits `IdentityUser` and the current user can be found by calling `FindById()` method of `AppUserManager`.

While `AppUserManager` can easily be instantiated using DI, how can I use DI the inject the output of the `FindById()` method? I cannot seem to find any documentation or sample code about this for Microsoft based framework. Other frameworks like Unity seem to support Property-based injection.

In essence, can DI be used with all existing classes or do you specifically need to code out the classes to support DI from the beginning? (i.e. only expect parameters to be passed in via constructors and make sure those instances themselves are created via constructors).

Comment: `how can I use DI the inject the output of the FindById() method?` - You shouldn't. This is *runtime data*, and the simplest way to "inject" it is to let it pass through the service methods as a parameter. If you want it to be "known" without passing it, you could inject a factory to retrieve it in each of your methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very simple and short answer to your question "Does Microsoft DependencyInjection support non-constructor injection?" is, no.

Out-the-box Microsoft DI does not currently support property injection like other frameworks such as Ninject. If you need that feature, I suggest using those frameworks instead (I cant imagine MS has any plans to add property injection any time soon).

Your other option is to consider how you can refactor your code to use constructor injection instead which is the preferred method